# How UPI apps like GPay verify phone number in the device?

Tags: android, sms, upi

How do they check if the phone number in device is same as user given phone number to sign up in GPay app?

**According to my research**

I am not sure, but, i think Gpay sends an SMS from user device containing the user given phone number to a server, there it's checked and reverted success/failure response via an API.

I have searched a lot here on SO and Google, didn't find any clear explaination to support my assumption.

Can someone please clarify how this process exactly works?

Comment: wow i wasn't expecting my question to get answered so quickly!

Comment: Can you please tell how you achieved this